# Send in a td element in a function callback to append the data from the ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, promise

I'm grabbing information from a PHP file and need to append the information to a TD element, however, whenever I try to do so I'm unable to send in the td as an argument to the callback handling the success of the AJAX call.

**Note**: The `td` element is really a `div` that acts like a table cell. Hence the variable name `td`.

Below is my code:

```
var bookingView = {
    //Creates a set of div elements
    createScheme: function() {
        //--- A lot of loops and if statements excluded here ---
        
        //The element that the data should be appended to
        var td = $('<div></div>'); 

        //Stores the returned promise
        var promise = bookingController.grabInfo('bookinginfo');

        //Send in the promise as an argument to display the information
        bookingController.displayData(promise);
    }
}

var bookingController = {
    
    grabInfo: function(filename) {
        //Return a promise
        return $.ajax({
            url : "ajax/" + filename + ".php",
            type: "POST"
        });
    },
    displayData: function(promise) {
        //If the AJAX CALL (or promise) was successful, append the data
        promise.success(function(data) { //Here is where I need to send in the td, but how?
            td.append(data); 
        });
    }
}
```

This is the solution I've been trying to apply to my own code: http://jsfiddle.net/jW68r/
but I can't get it to work since no matter what I do, the td element I need to append the information in always comes up undefined when I try to send it in as an argument to the callback function. Adding a second parameter called `element` and then writing `element.append(data)` simply doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

Comment: So debugging it, what is `data`??? Is success callback fired??? Etc.. FYI, `success` is deprecated, use `done` instead. Just wondering, are you adding `td` to the DOM??? `var td = $('<div></div>');` isn't adding element in the DOM. Maybe you just want: `td.append(data).appendTo('body')`

Comment: @A.Wolff data = <span>some text here</span>, yes it is fired. Ok will change. Yes I am adding it to the DOM in the excluded loops and if section.

Comment: As summarised in the question, the "excluded loops and if section" precedes creation of the `td` so cannot add it to the DOM. A better summary would include the `.append()` statement (or `.html()' or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that sending in the data to the callback itself doesn't work since the callback is run by itself. Using this worked however:

```
displayData: function(element, promise) {
    promise.done(function(data) {
        element.append(data);
    });
}
```

And calling it like so:

```
bookingController.displayData(td, promise);
```

Comment: Oh ya but you should have provided in question error in console